# sum field only if another row with a special condition exists

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following entries:

```
id customer amount kind
1  123      15     g
2  123      30     op
3  234      20     g
4  345      25     g
5  456      12     g
6  456      15     op
```

What I want to do is to sum all amounts with the kind "g".

Now I want to add a condition:

**"Only sum the amount to the sum if there is another entry of the customer with the kind 'op'"**

Means my result should be 27 in this case and not 72.

What's a good way to add this condition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the sum for each customer do

```
select customer, sum(case when kind = 'g' then amount else 0 end) as c_sum
from your_table
group by customer
having sum(kind = 'op') > 0
```

to get the total sum do

```
select sum(c_sum)
from 
(
    select customer, sum(case when kind = 'g' then amount else 0 end) as c_sum
    from your_table
    group by customer
    having sum(kind = 'op') > 0
) tmp
```